# Where is the input and output of this simple circuit?

Tags: diodes

[image]

I was instructed to put in a voltage probe at the input and the output of this circuit. Did I place the probes correctly?

Comment: Yes, green input, blue output.  Looks like a half wave rectifier

Answer (score 3):

That circuit only has three nodes - the two you marked, and Ground - so the two points you marked are the only possible points to measure.